# Clean install Mac, restore backup without command line tools

Tags: macos, time-machine, restore, homebrew

So, I'm a developer with brew installed along with several other programs installed from source(openCV, boost etc.). I want to do a clean install of OSX(to get rid of some other issues as well), then restore from a time machine backup(I have important apps and files I need to restore). Is there any way I can exclude my user installed command line tools from the restore? (effectively, starting afresh there?)

EDIT: I've just discovered you can [exclude the system folder](http://pondini.org/TM/10.html). This should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in totality, deselecting "System" worked. I now have a clean slate, while the rest of my apps still work.